# How do I set a proxy in Android phones?

Tags: android

Am really wondering how to set a proxy server in android phone like [tattoo] 
in order to gain access in some private networks

any suggestion would be appreciated ...

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally i got what i want
and here is the result :

There is no UI for proxy settings for android web browser. But the android web browser will read the proxy settings in its settings database.
Here is the instructions to enable the proxy in the android web browser.

1. `adb shell`
2. **`sqlite3 /data/data/com.google.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db`**
3. `sqlite> INSERT INTO system VALUES(99,'http_proxy', 'proxy:port');`
4. `sqlite>.exit`

source: http://discuz-android.blogspot.com/2008/01/set-proxy-for-android-web-browser.html

Comment: Can this be done on the real phone, not emulator? Moreover, can it be done on a phone that has not been rooted? Have you found out?

Comment: I think it cannot be considerated as a feasible solution. Plus it doesn't work on 2.x Android versions.

Comment: Inserting into `global` table will also be ok.

Comment: I have error: "No such table: system". When I go to sqlite3 and this location and type ".tables" I have empty database. When I type ".databases" I can see "main". I use Android Emulator, nexus4, api23. Please help.

Comment: That does not work any more (if it even had before).

Comment: its almost 8 years answer , it reached its end of life :D

Answer (score 7):

If you have ADB access, this should work:

`adb shell settings put global http_proxy <address>:<port>`

However the setting will be lost with a reboot.

Answer (score 6):

For **Android 4.0.3** and up (don't know how far up though) [the following](http://androidforums.com/samsung-galaxy-s2-international/575301-proxy-settings-android-4-0-3-a.html#td_post_4602266) will work:

1. Go to Settings -> Wifi.
2. Long-click on your network and select 'Modify network'.
3. Scroll down to 'Show advanced options' which should show you the proxy options.
4. Edit your proxy settings as desired and save.

Comment: I suppose, he is asking for proxy server, not proxy client

Comment: This works on Android 5.0 too. (sadly, it's not working on Android 2.3)

Answer (score 2):

On CyanogenMod (source : http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/20002-web-proxy-setup/)

In CM6 there was a setting in the Wireless & Settings for the proxy.

In CM7 you have to long press on the desktop background.
Then in the list that pops up select `Custom Shortcut` - `Pick your activity` -
`Activities` - `Settings` - 
toward the bottom of this long list is `Proxy Settings`

Add this shortcut to your desktop. When you then click on the shortcut you can enter your proxy address and port number.

Comment: Thanks for this--I was wandering through menus trying to find the proxy settings in CM7

Answer (score 1):

I found something [here](http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/programming/android-how-to-set-proxy-for-android-browser/) that looks like it might work

```
package com.BrowserSettings;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class BrowserSettingsUI extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(),  
            Settings.System.HTTP_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:100");//enable proxy
                }catch (Exception ex){
                }
            }
        });

        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), 
            Settings.System.HTTP_PROXY, "");//disable proxy
                }catch (Exception ex){
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You must add

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS” />
```

to your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Froyo has no provision for setting up proxy per wifi connection. In that case, you setup your wifi and install->setup ProxyDroid - http://www.appbrain.com/app/proxydroid/org.proxydroid

Let me know if it does not work.

> Needs your phone rooted.

Answer (score -2):

You have to create Access Points which can then be configured with Proxy Settings for different provider networks.
Go to `Home->Menu->Settings->WirelessControls->MobileNetworks->Access Point Names create an APN and configure it for what ever provider you want`

Hope that helps..