# How can you set the http proxy programmatically?

Tags: android

I'm looking for a programmatic way to set-up http proxy settings for android handsets.  I've tried using android.provider.Settings.System.putString() to set System.HTTP_PROXY, but my call fails (I'm using a 2.2 emulator image at the moment). My code looks like:

```
if (System.putString(getContentResolver(), System.HTTP_PROXY, "10.10.2.1:8080")) {
    tv.append("put for HTTP_PROXY succeeded.\n");
}
else {
    tv.append("put for HTTP_PROXY failed.\n");
}
```

I've also added to my android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

..although it's not clear from the docs which permission, if any, is required.

I'm familiar with [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011432/how-do-i-set-a-proxy-in-android-phones), but the technique there requires manual adb commands, which require the SDK tools and (possibly) a rooted phone.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Ideally, I'd like away to set an http proxy that will be used for both data and wifi connections.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not possible to do this as a 3rd-party app. You get this message:

```
12-07 12:39:37.736: W/PackageManager(85): Not granting permission android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS to package com.mgranja.xxxxxxx (protectionLevel=3 flags=0xbe46)
```

Only apps that are signed with the same key as system apps can get this permission (i.e.: if you cook your own rom, you could add that funcionality)

More info about permission levels on this question, specially adamk's answer.

[Why are these permissions being refused?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476600/why-are-these-permissions-being-refused)

Comment: It probably would on older devices, I'm not sure about SElinux Enforcing rules...

Answer (score 12):

If you are limiting the use of proxies to your own application you can use the [Proxy](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Proxy.html) and [ProxySelector](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ProxySelector.html) API.

Comment: thanks for that info - unfortunately I'm trying to set the proxy generally on the device (so that all browsers will use it, for instance..).

Answer (score 3):

To set the proxy check Mike's answer;
Following is code snippet to retrieve proxy details

```
public static String getProxyDetails(Context context) {
        String proxyAddress = new String();
        try {
            if (IsPreIcs()) {
                proxyAddress = android.net.Proxy.getHost(context);
                if (proxyAddress == null || proxyAddress.equals("")) {
                    return proxyAddress;
                }
                proxyAddress += ":" + android.net.Proxy.getPort(context);
            } else {
                proxyAddress = System.getProperty("http.proxyHost");
                proxyAddress += ":" + System.getProperty("http.proxyPort");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //ignore
        }
        return proxyAddress;
    }
```

It'll return empty if some exception or no proxy detected;

Answer (score 1):

You can set the proxy for your application VM, but due to security reasons, third party apps may not have the functionality to set device proxy.

Answer (score 0):

I found something [here](http://alexmogurenko.com/blog/programming/android-how-to-set-proxy-for-android-browser/) that looks like it might work

```
package com.BrowserSettings;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.provider.Settings;

public class BrowserSettingsUI extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(),  
            Settings.System.HTTP_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:100");//enable proxy
                }catch (Exception ex){
                }
            }
        });

        final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), 
            Settings.System.HTTP_PROXY, "");//disable proxy
                }catch (Exception ex){
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You must add

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS” />
```

to your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to `call the com.android.settings.ProxySelector` activity and let the user to enter the proxy? It's stored globally, but seems that it doesn't support the standard Proxy and ProxySelector API (for this problem there is already another question: [How users/developers can set the Android's proxy configuration for versions 2.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446871/how-users-developers-can-set-the-androids-proxy-configuration-for-versions-2-x))