# global setting Connecting to authenticated proxy

Tags: java, android, http, https, proxy

I am looking for some code sample to allow me to change the global proxy settings of the android device to direct the http/https traffic to a proxy server that requires authentication with username/password credentials.

I came across this post [How can you set the http proxy programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629644/how-can-you-set-the-http-proxy-programatically)  but it does not seem to cater for authentication against the proxy server

Any suggestion would be welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the SandroProxy source code.
But it is overkill for what you need.
SandroProxyPlugin is project to get you start with.

http://code.google.com/p/sandrop/wiki/HowToInterceptTrafficOnMyOwn

http://code.google.com/p/sandrop/source/browse/projects/SandroProxyPlugin/

To set global proxy you will need rooted phone on os below 3.x. 
On 3.x or higher there is settings but can not be set from code I guess. 
Well... it can :), but you should rather not be doing this 
because it is security breach to just redirect traffic without user interaction/confirmation.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40506

On the other hand, proxy authentication with username/password is just adding http header.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

btw: send by sandroproxy support :)