# How can we use HTTP Proxy Server in Android through Android Application?

Tags: android, http, proxy, connection

I Want to set up HTTP Proxy Server through My Application.

```
 How Can I set up Proxy Server from my application ?
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ProxySelector api help at  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ProxySelector.html
and proxy API help at  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Proxy.html  also check this out  i think first answer is useful for you  [How can you set the http proxy programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629644/how-can-you-set-the-http-proxy-programatically)