# Bypass proxy to access localhost in android programmatically

Tags: android, proxy

I have HTTP server and my application which are running on locally in android device. 
To access the file on a local server I want to bypass the proxy localhost/127.0.0.1.

How to bypass the proxy programmatically in Android?

Comment: You will easily get an idea from this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629644/how-can-you-set-the-http-proxy-programatically

Comment: Does it mean that only on rooted device we can bypass the proxy for localhost/127.0.0.1?